# Unable to display image using Cloudinary and Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use cloudinary to save my images, the code below work to save images to cloudinary, but am unable to  display the image in my view.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {


    $image = $request->file('image');
    $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath    = 'images/';
    $image = $request->file('image')->getRealPath();;

    Cloudder::upload($image, null);

   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);

    $image_url= Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height"=>$height]);

    .
    .
    .

     return redirect ( route ('admin.book.index'));

    }
```

In my `view page`, I have this

```
      @foreach($books as $book)
      <div class="col-1-5">
        <div class="home-catalog-image">
        <a href="{{ $book->image_url }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="trending image" />
        </a>
        </div>
        <p class="author">{{ $book->author->name }}</p>
        <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($book -> name, 20) }}</h1>
      </div>
      @endforeach
```

I have already included this in my controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
        return view('bookpage')->with('books', $books);
    }
```

## **UPDATE**

During my research,I updated my code,but it return error

> Call to a member function move() on string

```
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath    = 'images/';
    $image = $request->file('image')->getRealPath();;

    Cloudder::upload($image, null);

   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);

    $image_url= Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height"=>$height]);

    //save to uploads directory

    $image->move(public_path("uploads"), $name);

    //Save images
    $this->saveImages($request, $image_url);
```

Comment: Where are you saving the cloudinary public id?

Comment: In `image_url` column in the database

Comment: Then why are you calling ` <img src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="trending image" />` instead of ` <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" alt="trending image" />`?

Comment: oh, how did I miss, thanks it work now

Comment: You can update your question with the right code for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from my view

```
      @foreach($books as $book)
      <div class="col-1-5">
        <div class="home-catalog-image">
        <a href="{{ $book->image_url }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" alt="trending image" />
        </a>
        </div>
        <p class="author">{{ $book->author->name }}</p>
        <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($book -> name, 20) }}</h1>
      </div>
      @endforeach
```